# Decimal aligning numeric columns in a gt table

Tags: r, gt

For presentation, sometimes numbers are required to be decimal aligned within their column in tables.

The `cols_align()` function in the `gt` package has only a centre, right or left option for aligning numbers.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

df <- tibble(left_aligned = c(1.22, 222),
       right_aligned = c(4300, 0.1223))

df_gt <- df %>% 
   gt() %>% 
  cols_align(columns = 1,
             align = "left") %>% 
  cols_align(columns = 2,
             align = "right") %>% 
  fmt_number(columns = 1,   # Format the numbers so they display the correct number of decimals
             rows = 1,
             decimals = 2) %>% 
  fmt_number(columns = 1,
             rows = 2,
             decimals = 0) %>% 
  fmt_number(columns = 2,
             rows = 1,
             decimals = 0) %>% 
  fmt_number(columns = 2,
             rows = 2,
             decimals = 4)

df_gt
```

[image]

Is there the ability to align the column by the decimal point instead?

So that it looked similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Looks like **kableextra** might have an option for this where it is discussed at [github](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/174). Not sure if it can carry over to **gt**

Comment: `right_aligned` doesn't do it for you?

Comment: @Edward no `right_aligned` does not work. My question was not clear enough sorry. I have edited it for clarity

Answer (score 0):

With new extention to this package `gtExtras` - you can do [it](https://rdrr.io/github/jthomasmock/gtExtras/man/fmt_pad_num.html).

**Using example from the question:**

```
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)

df <- data.frame(left_aligned = c(1.22, 222),
                 right_aligned = c(4300, 0.1223)) 
gt(df) %>%
    fmt_pad_num(columns = c(left_aligned, right_aligned))
```

**Output:**

[image]